# Declaring a table variable with a field that is a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
declare @t1 table       
(
    [TableName] [nvarchar](100), 
    [UniqueName] [nvarchar](100), 
    [FieldName] [nvarchar](100), 
    [TransID_1] [nvarchar](2000), 
    [TransID_2] [nvarchar](2000)
)
```

I need something like this:

```
declare @t1 table       
(
    [TableName] [nvarchar](100), 
    [UniqueName] [nvarchar](100), 
    [FieldName] [nvarchar](100), 
    [TransID_'' + @ID1 + ''] [nvarchar](2000), 
    [TransID_'' + @ID2 + ''] [nvarchar](2000)
)
```

because the two TransID fields are going to have different numbers and the field names need to include those numbers.  There's about 3,000 lines of code overall, and just trust me when I say I need to name them this way.

Anyway...  Can this be done?  If so, how?

Comment: Why do you need dynamic column names in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need dynamic sql for this , something like this.....

```
Declare @ID1 varchar(10) = '20' ,@ID2 varchar(10) = '30'

Declare @Sql Nvarchar(max) 

set @Sql = N'declare @t1 table       
            (
                [TableName] [nvarchar](100), 
                [UniqueName] [nvarchar](100), 
                [FieldName] [nvarchar](100), 
                [TransID_' + @ID1 + '] [nvarchar](2000), 
                [TransID_' + @ID2 + '] [nvarchar](2000)
            )
            select * from @t1'

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: A thing to note is that @t1 will only be in scope in that dynamic SQL part; you wont be able to reference it after the exec sp_executesql

Comment: @LordBaconPants I shuold have really mentioned this in my answer. anyway thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Had to tweak it a tiny bit to fit, but this pushed me in the right direction.  And I discovered the scope issue and included that in my tweak.